# how to make three row with multirow package

Tags: tables, multirow

[image]I have a code that prints a table with 2 rows. I want to keep format of it and change 2 rows into 3.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Family data set results}
\label{tbl::Fam}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|c!{\vrule width 2pt}l|l|c|c|c|}
%\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
\hline
\textbf{Column}&\textbf{Algorithm}&\textbf{min}&\textbf{max}&\textbf{std}l&\textbf{Column}&\textbf{Algorithm}&\textbf{min}&\textbf{max}&\textbf{std}\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{age}&Original&9&2.8&100&\multirow{2}{*}{employer\_type}&Original&13&2&10\\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}&PrivBayes&2&95&96&&PrivBayes&2&100&100\\\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{education\_level}&Original&7&2&98&\multirow{2}{*}{marital\_status}&Original&10&2&100\\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}&PrivBayes&2&6&96&&PrivBayes&2&6&100\\\hline
\hline %\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In this picture, I have 2 algorithms {Original, PrivBayes}. I want to change 2 algorithms into 3 algorithms with keeping the format of table.
Can you please help me to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Didn't you ask this already and get answers?

Comment: Can't find it, though ....

Comment: No I did not ask it before.

Comment: Your documentclass is not a standard class (at least in texlive)... but I tried with article and it works (I suggest to change documentclass to article for this MWE -I don't think that your specific class has something to do with the question and this way you help anyone who will try to compile-)... Also your question is not clear enough... To add a row you just typing the elements of the row under the last one (after last ///hline)... Do you want to make the last half of columns two new rows? Or what? (Your table already has 5 rows)

Comment: How wide is your textblock? The screenshot suggests that the table is currently *much* wider than the textblock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table appears to be considerably wider than the text block is. The easiest remedy would convert the table from a 10-column structure to a more-manageable (and easier on the readers' eyes) 5-column structure.

While you're at it, you may want to give the table a more "open" look, to invite the reader to actually look at and hopefully even absorb the information provided in the table. I suggest you (a) get rid of all vertical rules, (b) use fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules, (c) not use any **bold** fonts and (d) align the numbers in the three numeric columns on their (implicit) decimal markers.

Oh, and I wouldn't use any `\multirow` directives for the entries in the first column; they're simply not needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Family dataset results}
\label{tbl::Fam}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{3}{S[table-format=3.0]} @{}}
\toprule
Column&Algorithm&{min}&{max}&{std.dev.}\\
\midrule
age&Original &9&28&100\\
   &PrivBayes&2&95&96\\
   &ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
\addlinespace
education\_level&Original&7&28&98\\
                &PrivBayes&2&6&96\\
                &ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
\addlinespace
employer\_type&Original&13&2&10\\
              &PrivBayes&2&100&100\\
              &ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
\addlinespace
marital\_status&Original&10&20&100\\
               &PrivBayes&2&6&100\\
               &ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is very useful suggestion for me. I will apply it.

Comment: +1 But I think the OP has to delete "with keeping the format of table". Anyway (practical) aesthetics is always useful and as TeX users have to take it into account!

Comment: Also if OP have still a reason to include class1 and class2 rows from this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386977/how-to-create-one-column-for-several-columns-in-a-table he can just put them as first row with \multicolumn{c}{5}{class1 or 2} and may be separate two classes with a single \hline

Answer (score 1):

Here is how that can be done:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Family data set results}
\label{tbl::Fam}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|c!{\vrule width 2pt}l|l|c|c|c|}
%\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
\hline
\textbf{Column}&\textbf{Algorithm}&\textbf{min}&\textbf{max}&\textbf{std}l&\textbf{Column}&\textbf{Algorithm}&\textbf{min}&\textbf{max}&\textbf{std}\\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{age}&Original&9&2.8&100&\multirow{3}{*}{employer\_type}&Original&13&2&10\\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
&PrivBayes&2&95&96&&PrivBayes&2&100&100\\\cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
&ThirdAlg&100&100&100&&ThirdAlg&100&100&100\\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{education\_level}&Original&7&2&98&\multirow{3}{*}{marital\_status}&Original&10&2&100\\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
&PrivBayes&2&6&96&&PrivBayes&2&6&100\\\cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
&ThirdAlg&100&100&100&&ThirdAlg&100&100&100\\\hline
%\hline %\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Change 100s to your values... Also if you realy need the last \hline remove
the % from the row before \end{tabular}

Result:
[image]

In landscape or something that table width will be ok, the centering of caption will be ok too.

Edit: Changed second part multirows too because I forgot them before and because of that the right multirow cells was not centered.

Comment: +1. The "look" of the table would increase if all 8 `\cline` directives were omitted (or, at least, commented out).

Comment: @Mico "increase"? Sorry but my English are not very good... Do you mean it would be more beautiful?

Comment: @koleygr - Oops. I meant "improve", not "increase"! (I shouldn't start dashing off notes before having had a second cup of coffee in the morning!)

Comment: @Mico... No problem... I just thought it is some strange (and new) English for me... (Always English are strange for a Greek lol ). On the subject: I did not change anything as the OP wanted excactly the same style. Not even the "l" typo on first std column (it is a kind of style too :P )