# how to create one column for several columns in a table

Tags: tables, multirow

I have a code that group multiple columns as a one column. But I have problem with separation of it.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Calculation}
    \label{tbl::agreement}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|c!{\vrule width 2pt}l|l|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{class1}{\vrule width 2pt}&\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{class2}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Column}&\textbf{Algorithm}&\textbf{min}&\textbf{max}&\textbf{std}&\textbf{Column}&\textbf{Algorithm}&\textbf{min}&\textbf{max}&\textbf{std}\\\hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{age}&Original&9&2.8&100&\multirow{3}{*}{age}&Original&13&2&10\\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
        &A&2&95&96&&A&2&100&100\\\cline{2-5} \cline{7-10}
        &B&100&100&100&&B&100&100&100\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

between class1 and class2 separation is thicker. And I want to group {Column, Algorithm, min, max, std} as class1 for left of table. But there is a split between {Column} and {Algorithm}. Can you please help me?

Comment: in second class you have multicolumn{5}... Why \multicolumn{4} in first class have to do the same? Make it 5 too snd remove & before it

Comment: Also remove {\vrule width 2pt} after class1. I suggest not to copy the table style and replacing pieces, but just count (l,c,r etc) and try to have the same elements in amount between & symbol that means (column separator)

Comment: If I change \multicolumn{4} in first class into \multicolumn{5} it throws an error. `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.<template> \endtemplate ...{|c|}{class1}&\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{class2}`

Comment: Yes because of the & before it... I told you to delete it...

Comment: How does this query differ from the one you posted [earlier today](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386973/5001)?

Comment: The difference is that here he tried to use multicolumn command... before he was trying to use multirow... The question is different but anyway he doesn't need it!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an explanation of your code. Try to understand these rules and you can go faster than asking one by one any new addition:

1)Starting the tabular:
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
will:
a) begin a tabular with starting vertical separator in every column
b) a left aligned first column
c) a vertical separator between this first column and the following column
d) a centered second column
e) another vertical separator
f) a right alligned third column
g) a last vertical separator (ending the table)

2) this command will be follwed by
    \end{tabular}
to close

3) Between the begin and end tabular are the rows.

Every row will have 3 elements separated by the symbol "&" which during the 
compilation become a vertical line.

The row always ends with \\ and if you want to have horizontal separator from the next line you add an \hline

If you want to have a line only for 2 first columns and not 3d you add
\cline{1-2} (1 is which column horizontal line starts and 2 which column ends)

That was the basic for a table

Next step in your table is to understand that !{\vrule width 2pt} is just another style of separator of columns (thicker than "|")

And last to know is that multicolumn command takes two arguments. First is the style (l for left, c for centered etc but it also overrides the tabular options and has to contain vertical separator too -sometimes this becomes tricky but you will see it and play to fix the double typed separator-). The second option is just the content of the "multicell"...

If you understand these rules you can already do much things.

Finally, in your code change the first contents row to:

```
\multicolumn{5}{|c}{class1}&\multicolumn{5}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c|}{class2}\\
```

Comment: I read again my answer and may be sounds somehow offensive. Sorry if sounds like this to you too. I just thought that this way my help will be more useful for you because I realized you don't really understand how these commands are working.